# Microsoft Graph Beta - How to get attendance report of a breakout room

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm currently using Microsoft Graph API beta to get all the attendance reports for an online meeting, both with delegated and application token.

My end goal is to sum the seconds of attendance for each attendee of a meeting. For this I get all records for each attendance report:

```
attendanceReports = await _graphClientProviderService.ApplicationGraphServiceClient.Users[organizerId].OnlineMeetings[onlineMeetingId].AttendanceReports.Request().GetAsync();                   

foreach (MeetingAttendanceReport at in attendanceReports.CurrentPage)
{
    attendanceReport = await _graphClientProviderService.ApplicationGraphServiceClient.Users[organizerId].OnlineMeetings[onlineMeetingId].AttendanceReports[at.Id].Request().Expand("AttendanceRecords").GetAsync();
    allRecords.AddRange(attendanceReport.AttendanceRecords.CurrentPage);
}
```

The issue comes when breakout rooms are created for the online meeting. I have not been able to find a relation between the primary meeting, for which I have it's id, with the breakout rooms.

Steps followed for testing:

1. Create an online meeting through:

   await _graphClientProviderService.ApplicationGraphServiceClient.Users[onlineMeeting.Participants.Organizer.Identity.User.Id].OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting);

*Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

2. Start the online meeting with the URL, as instructor.
3. Enter online meeting as test user 1 & test user 2
4. As instructor, create two breakout rooms and assign one user to each breakout room.
5. Close breakout rooms.
6. End meeting.

As an instructor, in Teams application, you can download 3 separate attendance reports for this example (located for download in each chat).

When I try to retrieve the list of attendance reports through:

```
attendanceReports = await _graphClientProviderService.ApplicationGraphServiceClient.Users[organizerId].OnlineMeetings[onlineMeetingId].AttendanceReports.Request().GetAsync();
```

*Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

Only the attendance reports for the online meeting are listed, not the breakout rooms reports.

Is there any way to get this data so I can also get the attendance reports for this rooms?

Comment: Could you please share the repro steps and documents you are following?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Sure. I have added them to the post for clarification

Comment: We tried to repro the issue at our end and faced similar issue. The attendance reports for the online meeting are listed, not the breakout rooms reports. We will confirm it from engineering team if this is by design or not and will inform you accordingly if we find any alternative way.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any API available to get the breakout rooms reports. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any API available to get the breakout rooms reports. Thanks!

The following article shows some limitations about attendance report for your reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/download-attendance-reports-in-teams-ae7cf170-530c-47d3-84c1-3aedac74d310